# Saving Maplex settings in style manager?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, maplex, style-manager

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop and I can see in the style manager that there is a part for Maplex.

Does anyone know how I can save Maplex settings for different features?

I tried using layer files but as the data I am working with is completely different it would be better to just click on a Maplex style.

Answer (score 6):

The Style Manager lets you create Maplex Label Styles, which define how a label will look and placement properties etc., but *will not save the label definition* (i.e. what field is labelled).

To create a new Maplex style, all you need to do is right-click in the empty space alongside where it says "Maplex Labels" and select New > Label...

[image]

You can copy label settings from one layer to another by using the Label Manager from the Labeling toolbar:

[image]

On the layer you want to copy label settings from, right-click and select Copy Parameters, then on the layer you want to copy them to, right-click and select Paste Parameters.  This will copy all the settings such as style, field name/definition, placement.

[image]

Comment: A nice, detailed answer, though the Label Manager screenshot is showing SLE properties... ;-)

Comment: @jon_two nice catch, I'll update tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't save maplex settings you have made. A workaround is to copy the feature class and to change the source to the new feature. 
Of course this feature has to be from the same type, point, line or polygon because the settings differ for each feature type.